# Mock useSitecoreContext in Nextjs unit tests

Tags: jss, unit-testing, nextjs

I'm trying to write simple unit tests with Jest and mock `useSitecoreContext`.
When I'm mocking the `useSitecoreContext` like this:

```
useSitecoreContext: jest.fn()
```

I'm getting an error `"Cannot destructure property 'sitecoreContext' of '(0 , _sitecoreJssNextjs.useSitecoreContext)(...)' as it is undefined."`

but if I don't mock it I'm getting a warning

```
Placeholder 'component-name' was not found in the current rendering data {
    "componentName": "componentName"
  }
```

Has anyone faced an issue like that? Or maybe some code examples of how to mock the hook properly?

Comment: Minimal reproducible example? https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Can you add some details as to what you are trying to test?

Comment: check if you have mocked your rendering data in your props